# Independence of the comprehension axiom

Tags: set-theory

What's wrong with the following line of reasoning, if so?

The comprehension axiom of Zermelo's set theory would be provable by the other axioms, if the following was provable:

> ($*$) All subclasses of a set are sets.

Then, especially all *definable* subclasses of a set were sets, which is essentially what the comprehension axiom says.

Since I assume that the comprehension axiom is *not* provable by the other axioms, ($*$) must not be provable. What does this mean? Are there models of set theory with subclasses of sets that are not sets?

Comment: Now when you say the axioms of $ZF$, do you include Replacement?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to include Replacement, so I changed ZF to Zermelo's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't translate your axiom "all subclasses of a set are sets" into a logical sentence of ZFC (with fist-order quantifiers, logical connectives, and $\in$). Since this sentence doesn't exist, you can't discuss its provability from the other axioms.

However you can probably translate it if you work with a richer language than the one of ZFC, like von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory

Comment: What would you say: Would there be only one model of set theory, if it was possible to translate "all subclasses of a set are sets" into the language of ZFC? But how could that be? Could "second order" help - like in the case of the induction axiom in PA?

Comment: I accepted this answer for the very first sentence which made everything clear.

Answer (score 3):

At the informal level, sure.  If ZFC has a model, it has a countable model.  That countable model, from the external point of view, has only countably many sets.

Now look at the picture of $\mathbb{N}$ in this model.  The class of all "real world" subsets of this is "really" uncountable.  So most of these subsets are not sets in our countable model of ZFC.

**Technical remarks**: In connection with the countable model assertion, I should have mentioned the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem.  And one needs in addition to show that the countable model can be chosen so that its elements are sets, and the $\in$ relation of the model is the ordinary $\in$ relation.  This can be done.